# How to show two regions have equal Area under Gauss map?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

What have I missed?

I'm trying to show that $N(A)$ and $N(B)$ have the same area, under the following conditions:

> 1. $N$ is the Gauss map $N: S \rightarrow S^2$.
> 2. The regions $A$ and $B$ on $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ share $\alpha \subset S$, a simple closed geodesic on $S$, as a common boundary.
> 3. $S$ is a regular compact surface with $K>0$ (Positive Gaussian curvature).

I've attempted the following:

given $K>0$, the map $N$ preserves orientation, therefore is a diffeomorphism from $S$ onto the sphere. Using the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem on region $A$, we have the following formula: $$\int_{\Gamma} \kappa_g(s) ds + \iint_A K d\sigma + \sum_{l=1}^p\theta_l = 2\pi\chi(A)$$ and since the geodesic curvature of $\Gamma$ vanishes on $S$, we have $k_g = 0 \implies  \int_{\Gamma} k_g(s) ds =0$. Also, since region $A$ is homeomorphic to a disk, the Euler characteristic is 1, hence RHS = $2\pi$.

Angle sum term would be zero because $\Gamma$ is a simple closed curve that bounds a region homeomorphic to a disk. Therefore 
$\iint_A K d\sigma = 2\pi$.

Since Gaussian curvature can be written as the ratio $\frac{\mid N_u x N_v\mid}{\mid X_u x X_v \mid}$, it follows that $$\mid ~N_u \times N_v\mid ~= ~\mid K \mid \cdot\mid X_u \times X_v \mid.$$ By integration,

Area of $N(A) = \iint_{N(A)} 1 = \iint_A\frac{\mid N_u x N_v\mid}{\mid X_u x X_v \mid} = \iint_A \mid K\mid = 2\pi$.

By the same argument, I get that $N(B)$ has the exact same area, $2\pi$.

However, I **have not used the fact that the regions $A$ and $B$ share a common boundary**, and am not sure where this piece of information would apply. What does a common boundary indicate, and is this information relevant to my approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, how do you know that $A$ is homeomorphic to a disk?

Comment: I think I've got it:  $K > 0$ implies, by Gauss-Bonnet, $\chi(S) > 0$ so the only possible value is $2 = 2 - 2g$ where $g$ is the genus of $S$.  Right?  That means $S$ is  a sphere.  So a closed geodesic must bound a region homeomorphic to a disk.  Right?

Comment: Yes, I'm following

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether the problem is asking to look at two regions that merely touch upon a common (segment of a) boundary, or whether they entirely share $\Gamma$ as whole boundaries, but where $A$ is not equal to $B$, so something like a complementary relationship (?)

Comment: If they share a common boundary $\alpha$, then they share it entirely.

Comment: Ah, I see how that is a necessary condition to conclude that $\iint_A K d\delta = \iint_B K d\delta$ from the Gauss-Bonet theorem

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct!